# XQuartz crash and infinite loop on Mojave

Tags: mojave, x11, xquartz

XQuartz is crashing constantly and going in an infinite loop on macOS Mojave.

On doing a `xinit` in the terminal I get:

```
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to Xserver : connection refused
xinit: server error
```

However, if I use it as root with `sudo xinit` it works.

How do I resolve this?